# build2: compiler does not support modules

Tags: c++, clang++, c++-modules, build2

I can build c++ projects without c++ modules with [build2](https://build2.org/), but when i try to configure and use build2 with c++ modules, I have "compiler does not support modules" error.

I'm sure my compiler is capable of building modules, because I can manually build using these commands:

```
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts --precompile foo.cppm -o foo.pcm
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts --precompile foo2.cppm -o foo2.pcm
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -c foo.pcm -o foo.o
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -c foo2.pcm -o foo2.o
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. foo.o foo2.o bar.cpp
```

Version of my clang is 7.0.0:

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 7.0.0- (trunk)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

To enable modules support in build2 I added following lines to root `buildfile`:

```
cxx.std = experimental

using cxx

assert $cxx.features.modules 'compiler does not support modules'

mxx{*}: extension = mxx
cxx{*}: extension = cxx
```

What can be wrong? It's my first time with build2, so I can be missing something very simple.

Comment: I created configuration with command `bdep init -C ../test-clang @clang cc config.cxx=clang++`, so, as I understand, it should use clang++. But if you know how to test it to be sure, please, tell me.)

Comment: I executed `b -V` and it seems it is going to compile with my clang++ 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed it to work.

As I understand the problem was that I changed `buildfile`, but should use `build/root.build` instead.